# In which cases using language with GC allows audio playback without dropouts?

Tags: c#, java, audio, garbage-collection, managed

As far as I know, using a language with Garbage Collection means there will be time intervals, inside which entire application is stopped. But I'm curious about the scope of this stops.

For example, there are `PortAudio` bindings for Java, and there are 2 modes of operation, which differ in control direction. In one mode you call PortAudio to put some data that it must play and in other mode PortAudio calls you (callback function) to fill its buffers with data. I am wondering, why Java bindings for PortAudio don't allow second mode (using callback). The explanation is, as can be read [here](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/classcom_1_1portaudio_1_1PortAudio.html): `This Java binding does not support audio callbacks because an audio callback should never block. Calling into a Java virtual machine might block for garbage collection or synchronization. So only the blocking read/write mode is supported.` This implies that in other case GC should not be a problem? *But why?* I don't understand this.

And how the situation will differ in other programming languages with GC? (especially interesting are C# and D.) What things should I take care of if I want to implement an audio player (that never ever drops out samples) in language with GC while using only 1 process? And is it possible at all?

Previously I was participating in developing a kind of VoIP software in Java and there was serious problems with dropouts which correlated in time with GCs. But doing music player should be easier, I think, because latency is not a problem here and I can use huge buffer for audio data.

### Update:

I am interested only in free and open source solutions. So, for example, using an "alternative" but non-free implementation of Java runtime is not an option for me to use. But it's interesting to know anyway.

Comment: Note that any answer necessarily depends on the details of the GC in question (which can vary quite a bit among JVMs and even within a single JVM). Some GCs guarantee a maximum pause time, other don't pause at all (except very briefly and rarely to copy the stack, hardly worth mentioning), while others don't give any guarantee. Some can be prevented from running by not allocating any memory, others may still run if you never allocate anything.

Comment: @delnan On HotSpot, all GC's pause and none gives a guaranteed maximum pause time. Some expend best effort towards limiting pauses. And as far as I know, none run when no allocation happens.

Comment: "As far as I know, using a language with Garbage Collection means there will be time intervals, inside which entire application is stopped." That assumption is wrong. You are thinking of a certain type of Garbage Collector, a 'stop-the-world' garbage collector. A concurrent garbage collector in theory doesn't stop the program at all. And there are real-time or near real-time GCs as delnan points out. 

 @MarkoTopolnik It depends the JVM. Some JVMs do have a real-time constrain on how long a GC cycle can be.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik yes, this is true about HotSpot - there is no way to completely get rid of pauses and even limiting max pause time doesn't work flawlessly (although it may be good enough if the application doesn't do anything related to audio/video I/O except plain GUI). And there it is also hard to stay with no allocations, because JVMs by design have no user-defined value types, but this is different story. I assume there WILL be allocations at least while user is interacting with GUI. And if this will cause dropouts, then this is no way...

Comment: @John good point. But in practice I haven't seen them. If you give some (not only theoretical) examples of no-pause GCs, this will be cool.

Comment: @SargeBorsch In real life, and especally with HotSpot's most modern G1 collector, the pauses are almost always quite short (say 100 ms or less). Short-lived objects (such as those created by GUI actions) are the least problem because they get handled by the extremely efficient minor collections (1 ms or less). So even a modest buffer size would be enough to bridge over them.

Comment: About your question, I don't think the difference between the two approaches is in problems you'll experience, but in API specification. Callbacks are *specified* as non-blocking (whatever that really means, I guess it just means very fast to execute), whereas the "push" mechanism puts the burden on the client so pauses are not PortAudio's concern.

Comment: http://www.amazon.com/dp/1420082795 can be an interesting read I hear for people interested in this subject. @SargeBorsch, the IBM Metronome GC is a realtime GC available in the IBM SDK for Java 7. Oracle's JVM does have some [limited] concurrent capabilities.